# WIN32 C-program with Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK : Getting Linker Error 'unresolved external' with time_t

Tags: c, winapi

I am writing a WIN32 C-program for a Motorola MC-55A PDA using Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK. I'm trying to get the current date and time. I tried to use time_t but I get a linker error: " unresolved external symbol time referenced in function BasicScanProc". I got no syntax errors. I've also tried to use the ctime function, the struct tm, SYSTEMTIME but they all fail with the same linker error above.

I've checked the  header file and all the above variables, structs and functions (time_t, ctime(), etc) have been declared in that header file but somehow I can't seem to use them in code. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

//Variables declaration
time_t current_time;

// Forward declarations
LRESULT CALLBACK BasicScanProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
void    ErrorExit(HWMD, UINT, LPTSTR);
LPTSTR  LoadMsg(UINT, LPTSTR, int);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPWSTR lpszCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    int nResult;

    hInst = hInstance;      // save the instance handle to a global variable
    nResult = DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG_SSCAN), NULL, 
                        BasicScanProc);

    return nResult;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK BasicScanProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD           dwResult;
    TCHAR           szLabelType[256];
    TCHAR           szLen[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR           szMsgBuf[256];
    LPSCAN_BUFFER   lpScanBuf;
    HWND            hctl_data, hctl_length, hctl_type, hctl1, hctl2, hWndComboBox;

switch(uMsg)
{

case WM_INITDIALOG:

//Below fails with error : 'time_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression  
//C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2\PocketPC\include\ARMV4I\stdlib.h : 
//see declaration of 'time_t'

current_time = time(NULL);
printf("Hours since January 1, 1970 = %ld\n", current_time/3600);

//This also fails
//time_t now;
//time(&now);
```

The contents of time.h for Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK is as below:-

```
/***
*time.h - definitions/declarations for time routines
*
*   Copyright (c) 1985-1994, Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
*
*Purpose:
*   This file has declarations of time routines and defines
*   the structure returned by the localtime and gmtime routines and
*   used by asctime.
*   [ANSI/System V]
*
****/

#ifndef _INC_TIME
#define _INC_TIME

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


/* Define _CRTAPI1 (for compatibility with the NT SDK) */

#ifndef _CRTAPI1
#if ( (_MSC_VER >= 800) && (_M_IX86 >= 300) )
#define _CRTAPI1 __cdecl
#else
#define _CRTAPI1
#endif
#endif


/* Define _CRTAPI2 (for compatibility with the NT SDK) */

#ifndef _CRTAPI2
#if ( (_MSC_VER >= 800) && (_M_IX86 >= 300) )
#define _CRTAPI2 __cdecl
#else
#define _CRTAPI2
#endif
#endif


/* Define _CRTIMP */

#ifndef _CRTIMP
#ifdef  _NTSDK
/* definition compatible with NT SDK */
#define _CRTIMP
#else   /* ndef _NTSDK */
/* current definition */
#ifdef  _DLL
#define _CRTIMP __declspec(dllimport)
#else   /* ndef _DLL */
#define _CRTIMP
#endif  /* _DLL */
#endif  /* _NTSDK */
#endif  /* _CRTIMP */


/* Define __cdecl for non-Microsoft compilers */

#if ( !defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__cdecl) )
#define __cdecl
#endif

#ifndef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned short wchar_t;
#define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#endif

/* Define the implementation defined time type */

#ifndef _TIME_T_DEFINED
typedef long time_t;        /* time value */
#define _TIME_T_DEFINED     /* avoid multiple def's of time_t */
#endif

#ifndef _CLOCK_T_DEFINED
typedef long clock_t;
#define _CLOCK_T_DEFINED
#endif

#ifndef _SIZE_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned int size_t;
#define _SIZE_T_DEFINED
#endif


/* Define NULL pointer value */

#ifndef NULL
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL    0
#else
#define NULL    ((void *)0)
#endif
#endif


#ifndef _TM_DEFINED
struct tm {
    int tm_sec; /* seconds after the minute - [0,59] */
    int tm_min; /* minutes after the hour - [0,59] */
    int tm_hour;    /* hours since midnight - [0,23] */
    int tm_mday;    /* day of the month - [1,31] */
    int tm_mon; /* months since January - [0,11] */
    int tm_year;    /* years since 1900 */
    int tm_wday;    /* days since Sunday - [0,6] */
    int tm_yday;    /* days since January 1 - [0,365] */
    int tm_isdst;   /* daylight savings time flag */
    };
#define _TM_DEFINED
#endif


/* Clock ticks macro - ANSI version */

#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  1000


/* Extern declarations for the global variables used by the ctime family of
 * routines.
 */

#ifdef  _NTSDK

#ifdef  _DLL

/* Declarations and definitions compatible with the NT SDK */

#define _daylight   (*_daylight_dll)
#define _timezone   (*_timezone_dll)

/* non-zero if daylight savings time is used */
extern int * _daylight_dll;

/* difference in seconds between GMT and local time */
extern long * _timezone_dll;

/* standard/daylight savings time zone names */
extern char ** _tzname;

#else   /* ndef _DLL */


#ifdef  _POSIX_
extern char * _rule;
#endif  /* _POSIX_ */

/* non-zero if daylight savings time is used */
extern int _daylight;

/* difference in seconds between GMT and local time */
extern long _timezone;

/* standard/daylight savings time zone names */
#ifdef  _POSIX_
extern char * tzname[2];
#else   /* ndef _POSIX_ */
extern char * _tzname[2];
#endif  /* _POSIX_ */

#endif  /* _DLL */

#else   /* ndef _NTSDK */

/* Current declarations and definitions */

#if defined(_DLL) && defined(_M_IX86)

#define _daylight   (*__p__daylight())
_CRTIMP int * __cdecl __p__daylight(void);

#define _timezone   (*__p__timezone())
_CRTIMP long * __cdecl __p__timezone(void);

#define _tzname     (__p__tzname())
_CRTIMP char ** __cdecl __p__tzname(void);

#else   /* !(defined(_DLL) && defined(_M_IX86)) */

/* non-zero if daylight savings time is used */
_CRTIMP extern int _daylight;

/* difference in seconds between GMT and local time */
_CRTIMP extern long _timezone;

/* standard/daylight savings time zone names */
_CRTIMP extern char * _tzname[2];

#endif  /* defined(_DLL) && defined(_M_IX86) */

#endif  /* _NTSDK */


/* Function prototypes */

_CRTIMP char * __cdecl asctime(const struct tm *);
_CRTIMP char * __cdecl ctime(const time_t *);
_CRTIMP clock_t __cdecl clock(void);

/*
_CRTIMP double __cdecl difftime(time_t, time_t);
*/

_CRTIMP struct tm * __cdecl gmtime(const time_t *);
_CRTIMP struct tm * __cdecl localtime(const time_t *);
_CRTIMP time_t __cdecl mktime(struct tm *);
_CRTIMP size_t __cdecl strftime(char *, size_t, const char *,
    const struct tm *);
_CRTIMP char * __cdecl _strdate(char *);
_CRTIMP char * __cdecl _strtime(char *);
_CRTIMP time_t __cdecl time(time_t *);

#ifdef  _POSIX_
_CRTIMP void __cdecl tzset(void);
#else
_CRTIMP void __cdecl _tzset(void);
#endif

/* --------- The following functions are OBSOLETE --------- */
/* The Win32 API GetLocalTime and SetLocalTime should be used instead. */
unsigned __cdecl _getsystime(struct tm *);
unsigned __cdecl _setsystime(struct tm *, unsigned);
/* --------- The preceding functions are OBSOLETE --------- */


#ifndef _SIZE_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned int size_t;
#define _SIZE_T_DEFINED
#endif

#ifndef _WTIME_DEFINED

/* wide function prototypes, also declared in wchar.h */

_CRTIMP wchar_t * __cdecl _wasctime(const struct tm *);
_CRTIMP wchar_t * __cdecl _wctime(const time_t *);
_CRTIMP size_t __cdecl wcsftime(wchar_t *, size_t, const char *,
    const struct tm *);
_CRTIMP wchar_t * __cdecl _wstrdate(wchar_t *);
_CRTIMP wchar_t * __cdecl _wstrtime(wchar_t *);

#define _WTIME_DEFINED
#endif


#if !__STDC__ || defined(_POSIX_)

/* Non-ANSI names for compatibility */

#define CLK_TCK  CLOCKS_PER_SEC

#ifdef  _NTSDK

/* Declarations and definitions compatible with the NT SDK */

#define daylight _daylight
/* timezone cannot be #defined to _timezone because of <sys/timeb.h> */

#ifndef _POSIX_
#define tzname  _tzname
#define tzset   _tzset
#endif /* _POSIX_ */

#else   /* ndef _NTSDK */

/* Current declarations */

_CRTIMP extern int daylight;
_CRTIMP extern long timezone;
_CRTIMP extern char * tzname[2];

_CRTIMP void __cdecl tzset(void);

#endif  /* _NTSDK */

#endif  /* __STDC__ */


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif  /* _INC_TIME */
```

How do I successfully get the current date and time in my C-program? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe the platform does not offer `time()`, check its documentation to see if it covers the date/time topic

Comment: M.M, the time() function has been declared in <time.h>, I checked.

Comment: Maybe it's not in the system library

Comment: I know it looks like black magic, but you can try to change the order of #includes to put windows.h and windowsx.h before time.h . If the linker complains about time_t, it is not time the missing function ; there's clearly somewhere the declaration of the symbol time_t, not only a typedef. You may also compile with `/E` option, to see everywhere `time_t` occurs. And for last : do you link with other obj or lib ?

Comment: Joel, thanks! Yes, I'm familiar with the reordering quirks for the header files and how they have to be arranged in order and also trying out both the #include <time.h> and #include "time.h" stuff..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` function was located in the C Run-Time Libraries. You could try to add  `/MD`or`/MDd` in compiler options to add the reference of the C Run-Time Libraries.

And `GetSystemTime`/`GetLocalTime` were located at Kernel32.lib according to the document. You could explicitly add a lib reference when using it:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Kernel32.lib")
```

The same as `time()`:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ucrtd.lib")
```

or other CRT lib in this document:
[CRT Library Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Glad to help and please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue.

Comment: @Ezani [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Aha! That little tick mark under the spin arrows! Done and thanks once again Drak!